# Conditional formatting with different formats in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

Here's the situation: I have a column with a completion rate from 0 to 138, followed by that value in percentage. ie: `66/138 (48%)`

I would like to use conditional formatting the change the colours of the cell depending on the percentage completion rate: one color if below 40%, another color if below 70% and a last color from 71 to 100%.

I know it's quite easy to do if the % was in another cell, but I cannot have that configuration. Moreover, I want to use the % for the formatting because I could have  completion rate from 0 to another value than 138 in the future.

Do you know how I could do this in the current state?

Thank you,
Loïc

[image: see the column sheet here]

Comment: does the numerator come from another cell and these are formula to display it the way you want?  If so just use that column as the reference.

Comment: no nothing comes from other columns, it's all there! It's actually content from a website but the data disappear after 48h and I copy paste to a spreadsheet to keep the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make the base fill base color, the color if the values were between 71 and 100 percent.  I chose Green.  This allows you to skip needing the third rule.

Then create two rules for the other two.

Both formula are similar:

```
=--MID(B1,FIND("(",B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND("(",B1)-2)<=40
```

Create the first rule and assign the color.  I used red.

Then the next formula will be:

```
=--MID(B1,FIND("(",B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND("(",B1)-2)<=70
```

Assign the color.  I used Yellow.

Then in the manager make sure the first rule is first and that it is marked to stop on True:

[image]

Comment: And it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!